# How can I add an article for a new language in Wikipedia?

Tags: wikipedia

I read an article on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/) and want to translate and edit it into my language.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1- Create the page in the new language

On the page you want to translate, change the language prefix (`xxx.wikipedia.org`) to your language's prefix. This will bring you to a blank page and Wikipedia will ask you if you want to edit it. If you don't know your language's prefix, find it by going to [www.wikipedia.org](http://www.wikipedia.org) where all the languages are listed.

For example, if you want to translate the article `en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange_Network` to Japanese, go to `ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange_Network` and find the link to edit the page.

However, it can most often be that the translation of the article has also a translated name. For example, if you translate the page [square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square) into french, you would not create the page `fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/square` but the page https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carr%C3%A9

### 2- Link the new created page to the other languages

a.  Once you have created the article in your language, let's say `fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carré` go to the page in an old language, e.g., english `en.wikipedio.org/Square` and there click on `Edit Links` under the languages names

[image]

b. Now, a site opens with a frame called just `wikipedia` and `Edit` on top of the languages: click again on this "Edit" link.

[image]

c. Finally you end up in the linking form. There you have to fill the fields `Site ID` with the language wiki id, for example, in our case is `frwiki` for the french wikipedia page. And fill the field `Sitelink` just with the name (**not** the full address!) of your new translated page, in our case, with `Carré`.

[image]

d. Click `Set the sitelink` and your translated page should be accessible from the main page of the other languages in the languages links.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore (2022), that link takes you to a WikiData site instead.